# Patterns in SVG

Tags: asymptote, pattern

I am trying to fill an irregular 2D shape with the hatch pattern in Asymptote and output it as svg. The result is a low resolution pixelated raster image. Is there a way to produce a vector pattern besides writing a from-scratch implementation?

Comment: Is this a tex related question?

Comment: @AFeldman: Asymptote and metapost questions are [generally considered on-topic](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3518/484).

Comment: Note that patterns (especially simple ones like `hatch`) are generally not used much in Asymptote because "implementing them from scratch" with a `for` loop is quite easy (about 3 lines, in the case of the hatch pattern). (Actually the same is true of TikZ *except* that it drastically increases compilation times, which is not the case for Asymptote.)

Comment: Can you add an example that shows the problem?

Comment: @CharlesStaats OK, I'll try to write a function :-) I am still very early in learning the Asymptote. Thanks for your titorial, BTW! I sincerely hope you will write more of them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution I came up with for the hatch pattern:

```
void hatchfill(path path_to_fill, real angle, real dist, pen p=currentpen)
{
    picture pic;
    pair p1 = min(path_to_fill);
    pair p2 = max(path_to_fill);
    real diag = abs(p2 - p1);
    pair center = 0.5 * (p1 + p2);

    for (int i = 0; i < floor(diag / dist); ++i)
    {
        pair strt = center - 0.5*(diag, diag) + i*(dist, 0);
        pair end = strt + (0, diag);
        draw(pic, rotate(angle, center)*(strt -- end), p);
    }

    clip(pic, path_to_fill);
    add(pic);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking of just `for (...) draw(...); clip(...);` (not inside a function), but you've made a general solution that doesn't have to be re-done every time.